# Control laptop video playback via iPhone

Tags: windows-7, laptop, video, iphone, remote-control

I've connected my windows7 laptop to my TV using an HDMI cable so that I can watch iplayer, youtube, google videos etc. Is there any way I can control the video playback remotely using my iPhone 3. I'd like to be able to pause, play, rewind etc the video playing.

Comment: Added Windows-7 and remote-control tags for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are numerous apps in the iTunes app store that will let you do this.

Firstly you need to decide if you need a keyboard or just a mouse clicker? Remember that Windows 7 has an excellent on-screen keyboard available.

In the case then of just needing a mouse clicker, you may want to consider a remote touchpad app such as [Touchpad from Splashtop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splashtop-touchpad/id414383034?mt=8).

If you need more, there are hundreds of apps to choose from. A selection are listed [here](http://appadvice.com/appguides/show/ipad-trackpad-and-remote-apps)

You could even go for a full desktop remote control tool. However, you should note that you will not be able to use Microsoft's built-in remote desktop (RDP) since that will close down the normal screen output. However, there are plenty of alternatives even here. You could use a VNC based remote screen or something like [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com).